# Find shortest path to corner in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have this following 2D int array (it's a board game). Given where my pawn 5 is, how do I determine the closest corner of the 4 corners (number 6) to the king (without minding the obstacles) I don't want the shortest oath here, I want the closest corner to the pawn 5. How can I get this?

```
013 | 6 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 
012 | 0 2 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
011 | 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
010 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
009 | 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
008 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 
007 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 
006 | 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
005 | 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
004 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
003 | 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
002 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
001 | 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6
```

I forgot to add my code: here's the part I started

```
public int findNearestKingExist(Board board) {
        int[] kingPos = board.findKing();

        int[][] grid = board.board;

        int x = kingPos[0];
        int y = kingPos[1];

        int topLeft = Math.abs(grid[x][y] + grid[0][0]);
        int bottLeft = Math.abs(grid[x][y] + grid[0][12]);
        int topRight = Math.abs(grid[x][y] + grid[12][0]);
        int bottRight = Math.abs(grid[x][y] + grid[12][12]);

        int shortestDistance = Math.min(Math.min(topLeft, topRight), Math.min(bottLeft, bottRight));

        return shortestDistance;
    }
```

Comment: Please also mention the code of what you have tried so far. It isn't a good practice to post question on so without details of what you have tried

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot !

Comment: @Jatin Updated, please have a look

Comment: You have an odd board size. What's the closest corner when you're in the middle?

Comment: Aside from that, what distance metric are you using? Manhattan distance and Euclidean distance being the more common candidates.

Comment: Hm, maybe number-of-king-moves as distance, the closest corner will be the one with the shortest distance, is it accurate @JohhnyBra? Its a 13x13 board strangely. But then I'm confused about the king and pawn, how are they related? do you want the closest korner for the king or the pawn or both?

Comment: I want the closest corner for the king

Comment: Manhattan distance sounds good. How do I implement it?

Comment: Just saw that in chess they use [different distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) for different figures, Manhattan, Chebyshev...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a Math Question.

Use Distance Formula, with the Array Indices as the coordinates, if you assume the array to be a quadrant of a cartesian graph.

Assuming you store your elements as grid[r][c]:
calculate the following :

```
int tl = (int) Math.pow(r, 2) +Math.pow(c, 2);
int tr = (int) Math.pow(grid.length - c, 2)  + Math.pow(r, 2);
int bl = (int) Math.pow(grid.length - r, 2)  + Math.pow(c, 2);
int br = (int) Math.pow(grid.length - c, 2)  + Math.pow(grid.length - r, 2);
```

then compare the ints, and the smallest one is the closest.

**Note:**

I have not square rooted the sums, as that does not change which point is the closest, just adds another step of unnecessary calculation.

I have also not subtracted 0 for all the coordinates that have an ordinate or abscissa as 0, for obvious reasons XD.

**Edit:**

Forgot to type cast to int.